# Transcode and stream library

Tags: encoding, streaming, video-streaming, video-encoding, vlc

I am looking for a desktop capture and stream solution.

I find [screen-capture-recorder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/screencapturer/files) to be very fast.
But I am pretty stuck in the transcoding and streaming process ( udp unicast )

I tried VLC but I am getting high latency or bad quality.

What is the best Transcode and stream library ( free or commercial ) ?

Comment: Try to stream in *UDP multicast* rather than *UDP unicast*. IP multicasts create a copy of a stream and this stream will be shared by all members of a designated multicast group. This helps in bandwidth saving. On the other hand, IP unicast works in point-to-point; having many instances of point-to-point create many copies of the same stream and they will rob the network bandwidth. Bandwidth is adversely affected by loss rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you confident that VLC is the source of the quality problem you are experiencing?  Have you modified any of the encoder settings?  You've not mentioned anything about the codecs, bitrates, etc.

Another option would be the open source [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org), which is in the same league as VLC.